# Does the PIC handle non-maskable interrupts?

Tags: assembly, x86, hardware, interrupt, cpu-architecture

Is there a separate communication bus for non-maskable interrupts that bypasses the programmable interrupt controller?

Or does the PIC manage all interrupts but passes all non-maskable ones along by convention?

Is this dependant of the architecture or are there specific reasons to prefer one over the other in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer is from some hardware experience that I gained while designing computers a long long time ago in a galaxy far away ... so long ago that I thought I should get a bit of help from a reference. I discovered a place to download [Intel's ia32 64 bit system software development manual](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/doc/manual/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-3a-3b-system-programming-manual.pdf) when I was perusing SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422708/how-to-send-nmi-on-same-system).

The answer to your first question is that the NMI is a pin on the processor which is isolated from the maskable interrupts which are configured with the PIC.

The answer to your second question is that the PIC doesn't have anything to do with NMI's. However if you have a an APIC, or Advanced Programmable Interrupt Controller, it is possible to generate an NMI as outlined in the manual:

> The processor receives a message on the system bus (Pentium 4, Intel Core Duo, Intel Core 2, Intel Atom, and Intel Xeon processors) or the APIC serial bus (P6 family and Pentium processors) with a delivery mode NMI.

The answer to your third question can be seen in the answer to your second. That is, if you have an APIC (not just a PIC) in your hardware. If you want a few more details about how the APIC can send an NMI, have a look at the SO link I've provided. I didn't go into the details here because you were asking about the "lowly" PIC, not the APIC. But just in case I misunderstood you, I think you will find plenty of information on the SO link, and if that is not enough, then go ahead and download the Intel manual.

I hope that clears a few things up. CHEERS!

Answer (score 2):

PIC (programmable interrupt controller) does not manage NMIs (non-maskable interrupts) in x86. NMIs go directly to the processor or via another controller, eg. ISP. See [OSDev: Non Maskable Interrupt](http://wiki.osdev.org/Non_Maskable_Interrupt).

However, according to [link](http://www.superfrink.net/athenaeum/OS-FAQ/os-faq-pics.html), you can disable NMIs this way:

```
/* enable the NMI */
void NMI_enable(void)
{
    outb(0x70, inb(0x70)&0x7F);
}

/* disable the NMI */
void NMI_disable(void)
{
    outb(0x70, inb(0x70)|=0x80);
}
```